# How to find whether MySQL is installed in Red Hat?

Tags: linux, redhat, status

I am currently using Red Hat linux. I just want to find out whether MySQL is installed in that system. If yes where is it located? can anyone help please...

Answer (score 30):

Type `mysql --version` to see if it is installed.

To find location use `find -name mysql`.

Comment: `find -name mysql` will only work if your working directory is `/` or `/usr` (or whatever component of the `mysql` location). `which mysql` is better if you want to locate a binary as it searches in the directories of `$PATH` only.

Answer (score 18):

If you're looking for the RPM.

```
rpm -qa | grep MySQL
```

Most of it's data is stored in /var/lib/mysql so that's another good place to look.

If it is installed

```
which mysql
```

will give you the location of the binary.

You could also do an

```
updatedb
```

and a

```
locate mysql
```

to find any mysql files.

Answer (score 5):

`yum list installed | grep mysql`

Then if it's not installed you can do (as root)

```
yum install mysql -y
```

Answer (score 1):

to ckeck the status use the below command, which worked on debian....

> **/etc/init.d/mysql status**

to start my sql server use the below command

> **/etc/init.d/mysql start**

to stop the server use the below command

> **/etc/init.d/mysql stop**

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can find a program under a subdirectory "../bin".
System programs are under /usr/bin or /bin. To check where files of mysql package are placed, on RHEL 6 type like this :

> **rpm -ql mysql**  *(which is the main part of the package)*

and the result is a list of "exe" files such as "mysqladmin" tool. About to know the version of the server, run the command:

> **mysqladmin -u "valid-user" version**

Answer (score 0):

`rpmquery <package Name>` By this command you can check which package is installed.

For Example: `rpmquery mysql`